# Delete a project from AEM 6.4

Tags: maven, aem-6

How do we delete a project from AEM 6.4 using cmd (mvn commands)?

I have created a project testproject in AEM 6.4 instance , now i want to delete the project testproject from the instance, how do we do that so all its dependencies and other things also are removed

Will delelting the project folder from crx/de delete it's dependencies??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a project from AEM instance their are few steps. First uninstall the bundle from the console this removes your java code. Then uninstall the package from crxde.

Another shortcut if you want to delete from local environment and dont have anything else to be saved then just delete the crx-quickstart folder.